# How to unnest an object (dictionary of arrays) in python?

Tags: python

I am trying to port code from R to python, part of which converts and object to different object using `data <- tidyr::unnest(data)`.

I have tried different ways like `pd.json_normalize(df, sep=' '), pd.DataFrame(A).explode('id')` but not getting desired output.

Input object:

```
{
  "id": [
    "3",
    "3",
    "3",
  ],
  "a": [
    "1",
    "1",
    "1",
  ],
  "b": [
    "1",
    "2",
    "3",
  ],
  "c": [
    "1",
    "1",
    "1",
  ],
  "d": [
    "1",
    "1",
    "1",
  ],
  "e": [
    0,
    0,
    0,
  ]
}
```

desired output object:

```
"id" "a" "b" "c" "d" "e"
"3" "1" "1" "1" "1" 0
"3" "1" "2" "1" "1" 0
"3" "1" "3" "1" "1" 0
"3" "1" "4" "1" "1" 0
"3" "1" "5" "1" "1" 0
```

Thanks,

Comment: Why does the "b" column have values of "4" and "5"? In fact, why are there 5 significant rows?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your data doesn't line up with your output but essentially you want:

```py
pd.DataFrame.from_dict(d, orient = "index").transpose()

  id  a  b  c  d  e
0  3  1  1  1  1  0
1  3  1  2  1  1  0
2  3  1  3  1  1  0
```

If you must have this exact output from your input you can do:

```py
df = (
    pd.DataFrame
    .from_dict(d, orient = "index")
    .transpose()
    .reindex((range(5)))
    .apply(pd.to_numeric)
)
cols = list(set(df.columns).difference("b"))
df[cols] = df[cols].ffill()
df.interpolate('slinear', fill_value='extrapolate', limit_direction='both', axis=0)

    id    a    b    c    d    e
0  3.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  0.0
1  3.0  1.0  2.0  1.0  1.0  0.0
2  3.0  1.0  3.0  1.0  1.0  0.0
3  3.0  1.0  4.0  1.0  1.0  0.0
4  3.0  1.0  5.0  1.0  1.0  0.0
```

Comment: @SamR  In what sense does the output from this answer match the requirement shown in the question? None of the value lists contain more than 3 values.

Comment: @CtrlZ the data in the question was edited after I posted my answer. `c` originally had four values. I have now edited the answer to reflect the data currently in the question.

Answer (score 0):

Without the aid of a dataframe you could do this:

```
def fmt(x):
    return f'"{x}"' if isinstance(x, str) else x

print(*map(fmt, data.keys()))

for t in zip(*data.values()):
    print(*map(fmt, t))
```

It's implied here that all of the list values in the data dictionary have the same length. In the question we see values of "4" and "5" in column "b". Assuming that's a typo.

**Output:**

```
"id" "a" "b" "c" "d" "e"
"3" "1" "1" "1" "1" 0
"3" "1" "2" "1" "1" 0
"3" "1" "3" "1" "1" 0
```